# How to get the permission alert click event in (.plist) privacy usage description?

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, alert, plist

In the plist setting "Privacy - Camera Usage Description", it shows a permission alert to allow or deny usage of the camera.

How can I get the alert's accept or refuse button event to do something? Here is my .plist file snapshot:

[image]

Comment: You just read permissions after as explained elsewhere. Just search for reading camera permissions and also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios

Comment: it work thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request camera permission using

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { granted in }
```

and you'll get the user's response in the `granted` parameter of the closure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use func `requestAuthorization(_:)` of `PHPhotoLibrary` to get authorization status.